# Override Reinforced.Typings CodeGenerator globally

Tags: c#, .net-core, reinforced-typings

`Reinforced.Typings` has support for custom Code Generators and Visitors. In order to print `@deprecated` for all `[Obsolete]` classes, interfaces, methods, properties, enums, etc. I want to add a Custom Generator for each which just does:

```cs
public override RtInterface GenerateNode(Type element, RtInterface result, TypeResolver resolver)
{
    var result = base.GenerateNode(element, result, resolver);

    if (Attribute.IsDefined(element, typeof(ObsoleteAttribute))) {
        result.Documentation.TagToDescription
            .Add(new Tuple<DocTag, string>(DocTag.Deprecated, ""));
    }

    return result;
}
```

I've also tried using a Visitor, but wasn't able to get from RtField, back to the type to determine which member is being called. I assume Blueprints are long gone by the time Visitors are Visited.

```cs
public override void Visit(RtField node)
{
    var type = ExportContext.CurrentBlueprint.Type;

    if (Attribute.IsDefined(type, typeof(ObsoleteAttribute))) {
        node.Documentation.TagToDescription
            .Add(new Tuple<DocTag, string>(
                Reinforced.Typings.Ast.DocTag.Deprecated, null
            ));
    }

    base.Visit(node);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only answer I could find to this on my own was to add a duplicate Attribute as displayed in the docs:

https://github.com/reinforced/Reinforced.Typings/wiki/Code-Generators#with-attributes-configuration

```cs
    public class TsDeprecatedInterfaceAttribute : TsInterfaceAttribute
    {
        public TsDeprecatedInterfaceAttribute()
        {
            CodeGeneratorType = typeof(TsDeprecatedInterfaceCodeGenerator);
        }
    }

    [Obsolete("Please don't use me.")]
    [TsDeprecatedInterface]
    public MyTsClass
    {
    }
```

You may choose to override the message in the Attribute, which could be useful. However, I'll know to check the C# for the deprecation message so I've left this part out.